# Attach Multiple Files in Lotus Notes Web

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I want a File Upload Control to attach multiple files in a Lotus Notes web form (document) in one go, I tried following

Added a File Upload Control to a Notes form
Open its properties and go to tab "", Add "multiple" to the field "Other"

But this doesn't work for Internet Explorer less than 9, most of the user are using 7 or 8.

Can anyone please help me in this regard.

Comment: You mention a file upload control. Are you using XPages?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a Lotus Notes limitation.  Multiple file upload in a single control is new in HTML 5, so it will only work on recent browser versions.

Your only alternative is to include multiple file upload controls.

Details on what browsers support this feature:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=forms